# Port Forwarding Issue

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, ports

I am confused over some issues with ports and port forwardings.

I have my own small datacenter running from my home. I have multiple web servers exchange server and all.

I have setup port forwarders for ports 80 and 443 to exchange server and of course have my public DNS point to public facing IP of my router.

now I Have my SharePoint servers with multiple web application and all and I have set those ports to 4242 and 4343. and I have port forwarded ports 4343 and 4242 to the SharePoint server. and again of course I have created a record called intranet on my public DNS pointing to the routers public facing IP. Now my questions is:

does people from internet have to type the port number after the URL? for example intranet.mydomain.com:4242????? cuz when I type intranet.mydomain.com it forwards it to my exchange server webapp which originally port 80 and 443 is forwarded to?

if yes how can I resolve this issue that users don't have to type :4242 after the URL

Answer (score -1):

For port forwarding what you will do is to call your internet provider so you dont need to type the port numbers after the URL. I know that ISP`s can do port opening and forwarding as well. In your case they need to open the port on your router in this way you dont need to type the port #s after the URL